# Printing out ! with printf inside swift code

Tags: swift, bash, openssl, printf, echo

I'm attempting to encrypt a string with openssl. The string that is to be encrypted is a randomly generated string consisting of letters, numbers, and symbols. The following command is run to attempt to encrypt the string:

```
printf "randomString" | openssl enc -base64 -e -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass: "passwordSalt"
```

This works fine as long as there weren't any characters generated in the string that printf doesn't like. I've seen other posts about handling a `%` by putting two percentage's together `%%`.

However, issues arise if there is a `!` in the string. Other sources say to single quote the string instead of double quoting, as double quoting causes bash to interpolate the string. This wouldn't be an issue if I were just running this in the command line. The `printf` and openssl commands are being run in swift as a `Process()` and unfortunately there is no such thing as single quotes in swift. I've even tried to enclose the string in single quotes after it's generated but that causes the single quotes to be part of the string during encryption. Is there any way or any option provided with printf that allows the use of a ! in a string when double quotes aren't an option? `echo` also works in a similar fashion, where single quoting works but double quotes interpolates certain characters, but I will be fine with using `echo` or `printf`.

Comment: If your problem is with running the command from Swift, it would be helpful to post a small demo of how you're doing that. The issue could be with how you're running the command from Swift rather than a problem with the bash logic itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop mucking about with `printf` and just write the input string directly to the standard input of `openssl`. Then you don't need to worry about quoting weird characters.

```
import Foundation

func encrypt(_ plainText: String) async throws -> String? {
    let pipeToChild = Pipe()
    let fileHandleToChild = pipeToChild.fileHandleForWriting
    let pipeFromChild = Pipe()
    let fileHandleFromChild = pipeFromChild.fileHandleForReading
    let child = Process()
    child.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/openssl")
    child.arguments = [
        "enc",
        "-base64",
        "-e",
        "-aes-256-cbc",
        "-salt",
        "-pass", "pass:passwordSalt"
    ]
    child.standardInput = pipeToChild
    child.standardOutput = pipeFromChild
    try child.run()

    async let writeResult: () = Task {
        try fileHandleToChild.write(contentsOf: plainText.data(using: .utf8)!)
        try fileHandleToChild.close()
    }.value

    async let readResult = Task {
        try fileHandleFromChild.readToEnd()
    }.value

    let _ = try await writeResult
    let data = try await readResult

    return data.flatMap { String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) }
}

@main
struct MyMain {
    static func main() async {
        do {
            let answer = try await encrypt(#"string with \/\/eird ${embedded} "c"harac't'ers"#)
            print(answer ?? "(failed to encrypt)")
        }

        catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

Here is a version that doesn't use `async`. It could in theory deadlock if `openssl` tries to write substantial output before reading all of its input. It probably won't be a problem if the plaintext is no more than 4k.

```
import Foundation

func encrypt(_ plainText: String) throws -> String? {
    let pipeToChild = Pipe()
    let fileHandleToChild = pipeToChild.fileHandleForWriting
    let pipeFromChild = Pipe()
    let fileHandleFromChild = pipeFromChild.fileHandleForReading
    let child = Process()
    child.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/openssl")
    child.arguments = [
        "enc",
        "-base64",
        "-e",
        "-aes-256-cbc",
        "-salt",
        "-pass", "pass:passwordSalt"
    ]
    child.standardInput = pipeToChild
    child.standardOutput = pipeFromChild
    try child.run()

    try fileHandleToChild.write(contentsOf: plainText.data(using: .utf8)!)
    try fileHandleToChild.close()

    let data = try fileHandleFromChild.readToEnd()
    return data.flatMap { String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) }
}

@main
struct MyMain {
    static func main() {
        do {
            let answer = try encrypt(#"string with \/\/eird ${embedded} "c"harac't'ers"#)
            print(answer ?? "(failed to encrypt)")
        }

        catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is ideal as I never wanted to use another shell command to pipe to the openssl command but I think your use of concurrency is out of my level of knowledge. I'm attempting to incorporate what you wrote into my code, or at least a modified version of it but I can't get it to work.

Comment: My issue currently with attempting to implement your code is that the @main portion doesn't want to be the entry point of the code. It states:
'main' attribute cannot be used in a module that contains top-level code

I have a separate struct with methods and class variables that I put outside of the MyMain struct which I think may be causing the issue but I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: The important part is the `encrypt` function. The `MyMain` struct is just there to make it a standalone demo.

Comment: Also, if the plain text is guaranteed to be small (say, under 4k) then you could eliminate the async/await stuff and just do a blocking write, close, and then read the result.

Comment: It seems removing all the async and await keywords from the function definition and the inner code of the func still gives me an issue with the Task enclosure. I removed those along with try await result variables. My code now runs but without successfully encrypting the string i.e. running the openssl command successfully.  I'm attempting put my code in here but it may contain too many characters.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
printf '%s' 'randomString' | openssl enc -base64 -e -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass: "passwordSalt"
```

to avoid interpreting special format chars by `printf`

#### edit

use single quotes

```
printf '%s' '!@#$%%^&*()_+=-0987654321\][{}|;:/.?>,<'
!@#$%%^&*()_+=-0987654321\][{}|;:/.?>,<
```

Comment: When I do a test run of that without the openssl stuff: 
```printf '%s' "!@#$%%^&*()_+=-0987654321\][{}|;:/.?>,<"```
```-bash: !@#$%%^: event not found```

Comment: I see you edited using single quotes, but that's my issue as the OP states. This command is being run as a subprocess in swift code and swift doesn't have single quotes :(

Comment: Probably [pitfall 23](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22Hello_World.21.22). Not a problem for noninteractive scripts, if you're testing on the command line try disabling history expansion with `set +H` before running the command.

Answer (score 0):

With assistance from @rob mayoff I was able to avoid the piping of printf/echo to openssl altogether. Although I do think it's still a topic that probably needs to be answered ultimately.
I was able to pipe a string to the openssl process in swift:

```
mutating func encryptString(_ plainText: String) throws -> String? {
   let pipeToChild = Pipe()
   let fileHandleToChild = pipeToChild.fileHandleForWriting
   let pipeFromChild = Pipe()
   let fileHandleFromChild = pipeFromChild.fileHandleForReading
   let child = Process()
   child.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/openssl")
   child.arguments = [
            "enc",
            "-base64",
            "-e",
            "-aes-256-cbc",
            "-salt",
            "-pass", "pass:\(self.passwordSalt)"
   ]
   child.standardInput = pipeToChild
   child.standardOutput = pipeFromChild
   try child.run()
   try fileHandleToChild.write(contentsOf: plainText.data(using: .utf8)!)
   try fileHandleToChild.close()
   var output = try fileHandleFromChild.readToEnd()
   var outputString = String(decoding: output!, as: UTF8.self)
   print("output: \(output!)")
   child.waitUntilExit()
   print("encrypted String: \(outputString)")
   self.encryptedPassword = outputString
   return "Success"
}
```